# Customizing Google Custom Search

Tags: forms, search, google-custom-search

Does anyone know how to remove the extra branding on the google custom search?

they've added a button and other things like text that says "gadgets powered by google".

there has to be a way to pipe the CSE data into a normal form, right?

http://www.google.com/coop/cse/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the normal way is to buy their [Business edition](http://groups.google.com/group/google-custom-search-creating-and-editing/browse_thread/thread/b0551aded8c00c15/1e26df13af8a9d95) ;)

Still there seems to be some [tweaking possible](http://markmail.org/message/fts56cobltlha5x4#query:%22google%20custom%20search%22%20remove%20text+page:1+mid:3htxsx5mx2kwovn4+state:results): this [custom search form](http://www.oakham.rutland.sch.uk/search/search.asp) does not look bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can make some tweaks by simply adding to your own CSS. The best part about these tweaks is that you don't need to be a paying customer!

Change font size and remove Google branding:

```
input.gsc-input {
   font-size: 11px; 
   height: 16px !important;
   background: none !important;
}
```

Change autocomplete font size:

```
.gsc-completion-container table {
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Change border radius of the search box:

```
.gsc-input-box {
    border-radius: 3px !important;
}
```

*** Hide Ads (my personal favorite)

```
.gsc-adBlockVertical, .gsc-adBlock { /* this hides both the top and right ad blocks*/
    display:none;
}
.gsc-thinWrapper { /* this gives you use of the whole block, as opposed to 69% google gives*/
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well the business edition's main benefit is that the search results don't have ads in them. so really google shouldn't care if people are modding the search form on the free service since it will still bring them ad revenue.

i looked at the page you linked to, it might out of date cause their latest code spits out javascript, so nothing's really clear.

i think there's a way to grab my api code and pop it into a normal form script.

Comment: I am not sure. However, you might complete your question with your latest searches and conclusions, and make that "answer" a comment to mine, rather than an independent post.

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 You can do this (on your standalone results page at least) with:

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .gcsc-find-more-on-google-branding {
      display: none!important;
    }
    .gsc-adBlock {
      display: none!important;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```